# Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, hmvc

I have created a codeigniter project (XYZ) in hmvc. Inside a project(ABC), i created app folder and uploaded XYZ project. So ABC.com works but ABC/app does not work. It says:

[image]

Comment: Something is messed up in your configs. Check if `subclass_prefix` is defined in your config file.

Comment: Yeah its defined well, i think we have problem with the second project accessing files properly

Comment: @BILALMALIK i think u did not get the problem identified. It's not with model or database, the problem is i uploaded a project inside a folder of another project such that it becomes ABC.com/XYZ where superadmins can login with their credentials. Now ABC.com works but not XYZ. And i have attached a snapshot of problem in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .htaccess then you have to allow XYZ folder name (app in your case) in ABC project .htaccess file.

Or Sometimes CodeIgniter won't find the controller.

Go to `config > routers.php`

and see the value of default_controller, update this as per your default controller.

Comment: In the XYZ foder, I went to the config > routes.php and added module's name which is same as the controllers' . Actually could you be more clear?

Comment: @ParashAgrawal What is the value of default_controller in config > routers.php of ABC project?

Comment: ABC and XYZ both have login controllers in their config files. So default_controller is "login"

Comment: Done. Actually, it was working fine before then i had to change the hosting .Hence, i uploaded the same project folder and updated database configurations. Now i have the above problem

Comment: Why you change the application folder path ?? It should be
$application_folder = 'application';
Assume your controller name is welcome. Then File name should be Welcome.php. And inside the file
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
}
In routes (application/config/routes.php)

$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';

Comment: I am sorry but these things are already there. I rechecked it as well